# How to conditionally render a css class with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have some html like the following:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.DealCode" name="DealCode" class="input-mini" />
</div>
```

However, `ifnot: $data.DealCodeIsValid`, I need to render the following:

```
<div class="control-group error">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.DealCode" name="DealCode" class="input-mini" />
</div>
```

Note the additional class "error" in the div. Is there a way to do that with knockoutjs?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Something like

```
<div data-bind="css: {'control-group': true, error: (!$data.DealCodeIsValid)}">
```

[Check here for more info](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

Comment: I found that about 10 minutes after posting this.  Thanks @jon.

Comment: @devlife thankfully jon posted this 8 minutes after u asked, so u saved 2 minutes. :P